# how to delete everything related to node.js from the filesystem?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find

I want to remove all node.js modules and sub-folders from my linux system in order to start over with a fresh install. I upgraded my system recently from Kubunto 14 to 16, did some backups and messed things up. An attempt to simply npm uninstall npm -g did not delete npm/node_modules so I guess I have to delete it all manually.

So the question is, how can I list all of the files that have "npm" or "node" in their name or path, so that I could rm them?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found how to find all files that match a pattern and last updated on a given date:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-list-all-files-modified-on-given-date/

From this I could track down anything npm on my system and delete it.